# "stacking" blocks?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Is it possible to invoke a block within another block?

For example:

```
-(void)doSomethingWithBlock:(void (^)(id))parameterBlock{

     Blah * object = [Blah doThisblock:^(id sender) {

     //invoke "parameterBlock" here..

     // do other things after as well..

     }
 }
```

If possible, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Do you mean "How do I call a block?"

Comment: yeah my bad.. found out how to do it, via: parameterBlock(); thanks for the reply though :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoke block iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484123/invoke-block-ios)

Comment: @BigRed Just note that if `paramaterBlock` is `nil` and you try to call it, an exception will be raised

Comment: Given the answer, what does this question have to do with calling a block from within a block? It seems the actual question was "how do I call a block?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I could call the block by doing this:

```
    -(void)doSomethingWithBlock:(void (^)(id))parameterBlock{

            Blah * object = [Blah doThisblock:^(id sender) {

                   parameterBlock();

                   // do other things after as well..

           }
     }
```

Comment: Get in the habit of writing... if (block) block();